# Numeric loop in an unrange of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to assign a number to a record (of in a range) and when it ends it starts from the first number of the range?

I currently have the following table:

| id | date | first_number | last_number | start_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 02/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 03/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 04/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 05/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 06/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 07/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 08/01/2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

I would like to get the value assignment in the cycle column based on start_range and last_range.
The start of the cycle must be the value of the first record (in example 2)

| id | date | first_number | last_number | start_number | cycle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 02/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 03/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 04/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 05/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 06/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 07/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 08/01/2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Have you looked at `ROW_NUMBER`? then you just need to add some integer maths.

Comment: thanks for the answer, currently I use the ROW_NUMBER to assign a progressive with a starting start, I would not know how to use it to insert a progressive starting from a start and start over if there is a max. Can you give me an example? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this, with a modulo operator and some addition:

```sql
SELECT id,
       date,
       first_number,
       last_number,
       start_number,
       ISNULL(NULLIF((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) + start_number - first_number) % last_number,0),last_number)
FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(date,'01/01/2021',103),1,3,2),
            (1,CONVERT(date,'02/01/2021',103),1,3,2),
            (1,CONVERT(date,'03/01/2021',103),1,3,2),
            (1,CONVERT(date,'04/01/2021',103),1,3,2),
            (1,CONVERT(date,'05/01/2021',103),1,3,2),
            (1,CONVERT(date,'06/01/2021',103),1,3,2),
            (1,CONVERT(date,'07/01/2021',103),1,3,2),
            (1,CONVERT(date,'08/01/2021',103),1,3,2))V(id,date,first_number,last_number,start_number);
```

The `ISNULL`/`NULLIF` are there to replace `0` with the last value.

You may/will need to add a `PARTITION BY` clause depending on your requirements for other `id` values.

Note that the results here don't match your expected results, as in your expected results `last_number` has a value of `4`, but has the value `3` in your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e232befce1393b548f3e47823fc4256)

```
 first_number+(start_number-first_number+row_number() over(order by date)-1)%(last_number+1-first_number) as cycle
```